# Display custom list of tags in post/page editor with hooks

Tags: tags, hooks, terms

I used the information posted on [this blog post](http://binfalse.de/2010/08/show-all-tags-in-wp-when-creating-new-post/) to display specific tags when editing a post.  The editors on my site wanted the ability to display pre-specified tags instead of the most popular ones.  We have a lot of tags and sometimes the ones they want to use are not being used because they are not seen and they don't remember what to search for.

So in the `wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php` file I changed the **line 651** to

```
$tags = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 
    'number' => 45, 
    'orderby' => 'name', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'include' => array('21', '12') 
) );
```

where the `include` array is the selection of tags I want to display.

and **line 665** to

```
$return = wp_generate_tag_cloud( $tags, array(
    'largest' => 10, 
    'smallest' => 10, 
    'filter' => 0, 
    'format' => 'flat', 
    'separator' => "  "
) );
```

This works fine for displaying a sequential list (I didn't want a tag cloud) of specific tags but these changes are to the wordpress core and on the next update I'll have to go in and re-do these.  Is there any way to accomplish this with hooks so that I don't mess with the core?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can override the [Ajax call](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/js/post.js#L110) to `wp_ajax_get_tagcloud()` and do a clean hack.

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Custom Admin Tag Cloud */

add_action( 'wp_ajax_get-tagcloud', 'ajax_tag_cloud_wpse_99497', 1 );

function ajax_tag_cloud_wpse_99497() 
{
    // PASTE ALL THE MODIFIED FUNCTION HERE
    // http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php#L639
}
```

Restore your core files to its original state, copy the modified function inside the above container and [create a plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615) for it. And ready to go.

Comment: Thanks, that worked just fine.

Additionally, if I wanted to override something like `post_tags_meta_box` from `wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php`, I could use this same method in my functions file?

Comment: Does it involve any Ajax? If not and depending on what you want to do, you have to [unset the meta box and create a modified clone](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Badd_meta_box+%2Bremove_meta_box+is%3Aanswer). Also, search the core file you're interested for available hooks: `do_action` and `apply_filters`. . . . PS: don't mis-use the functions file, see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615